# Ruby on Rails: assign relationship on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails. There are two models in my project: room and guest. The association is "room has_many guests" and "guest belongs to room".

I have separated views for manage rooms and guests. Rooms don't require "guests" value on creation. However, I want to create new guests and assign it to certain room at the same time. What will be the proper way to do it? How do I transfer the input from web and match the entities in database.

The code is pretty much the same as ["Getting Started with Rails"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). In the tutorial, they add "comments" in the "article" view and use "comment" as a sub-resource of "article". In my case, I treat the two models equally and want to manage them in separated views.

Update:

I used the collection_select and try to work with my guest_controller.

```
<%= form_for :guest, url: guests_path do |f| %>
<% if @guest.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= pluralize(@guest.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this guest from being added:
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% @guest.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :phone %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :room%><br>
    <%= f.text_field :room %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= f.label :room %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select(:room_id, Room.all, :id, :title) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', guests_path %>
```

In my guest_controller, the create method called by the form above is :

```
    def create
        @guest = Guest.new(guest_params)
        @guest.room = Room.find(params[:room_id])
        if @guest.save
            redirect_to @guest
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

However, when I create a new guest, it shows that:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in GuestsController#create
Couldn't find Room with 'id'=
```

I checked that room_id=4 and Room.find(4) return the proper room.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select one room from those that exist, use [`collection_select` form helper](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects), here is a relevant snippet from the docs:

```
f.collection_select(:city_id, City.all, :id, :name)
```

This outputs a dropdown list that:

- fills in `city_id` parameter in this context
- uses `City.all` for filling in the options in the list (I will be referring to "each" city as `city`)
- uses `city.id` as **data** (that gets sent in the form)
- shows `city.name` for each city in the dropdown list (hopefully, human-readable)

Bear in mind though, that in terms of security it's like *"look, you can select this, and this and this!"*, that does not prevent users from selecting an unlisted option: either by modifying form markup by hand or sending handcrafted queries.

So should you ever be limiting access to specific rooms, and list only `Room.unlocked` (`unlocked` assumed a scope), make sure the received `room_id` refers to a room from that scope as well. Most of these problems are dealt with using either validations or careful association management (`Room.unlocked.find_by_id(:room_id)` that outputs `nil` if the room is not in that scope).

**UPD:** as for the latest problem you're having -- your understanding on how the form contents look in `params` seems to be wrong. It's quite a common misconception actually.

`form_for :guest` will construct a separate object/hash in `params[:guest]`, with all the form's fields inside it. So it actually is inside `params[:guest][:room_id]`, but **no, don't rush with adding the missing part**.

You've already built a `@guest` object from entire `params[:guest]`, so if the room actually exists, it's inside `@guest.room` already and can be validated inside the model during `save`. Have a look at [Rails validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I used the collection_select and encountered new problems. Please check my update on the question. Thank you!

Comment: @HaoboChen Why do you need `@guest.room = Room.find(params[:room_id])` in your create action? There's no need to look for the room since your collection_select can only contain rooms that exist, so no need to check. As long as you have a room_id column in your Guest table and set it, the relation should be fine.

Comment: @thirdsun a form is submitted by the browser and can be tampered with.

Comment: @HaoboChen if you're not limiting the scope of allowed rooms, validating the presence of `room` should be good enough. Validations will be fired on `save` and will prevent references to non-existent rooms. Things only get complicated if there is some access control in place.

Comment: @D-side That's true, didn't think about that and missed the last part of your answer.

Comment: @HaoboChen updated. But in future, please ask such substantially separate questinos in separate questions (treat SO's questions and answers like real-life terms).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `fields_for` tag:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

It allows just that, to create a guest while creating a room and associating each other.

Comment: Actually, I want to create a guest and assign it to an existing room. Another problem will be what kind of input value do I need for identify the room.

Comment: If you need to assign to an existing room its pretty easy, @D-Side solution is one of them, the `belongs_to` association means there's a room_id column in the Guests model, so using a collection_select or check_box form item is enough to associate the guest to the room.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've made some update to my question. Please check it.